# SUMIF ignore negative number

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum

don't know how to solve this problem I am hitting my head into the wall for awhile now....
I need to calculate the sum of the profit but ignore cells that have "-0.31" number in them

my formula is:

```
=SUMIF(J2:J199,"<>-0.31")
```

what do I do wrong?? Some help, please. Unfortunately, the "-0.31" it's still calculated in this formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two separate SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(J2:J199,"<-0.315")+SUMIF(J2:J199,">=-0.305")
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(J2:J199*(ROUND(J2:J199,2)<>-0.31))
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic but nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: @maxxi the number is not exactly -0.31, so it needs a bit of rounding.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=SUMIF(J2:J199,"<>"&-0.31)
```

Comment: What if you're values are not exactly -0.31? Let's say -0.3100001. Could you check that?

Comment: Same issue, does it have anything with the fact that in my cells that have "-0.31" it's actually a formula that gives this value?

Comment: In each Profit cell (J2:J199) there is a formula that gives that respective value, is just most have "-0.31" and in Sum I want to ignore those "-0.31" values.

Comment: Are they rounded?

Comment: yeah, all are: 1.30 , 1.20, 3.35 , -0.10 , etc

Comment: Found the solution, thank you very much nevertheless Vinnie!